# Need to change my technology

Tags: hadoop, hive, apache-pig, bigdata

I have exprience of 1.6 year.
Currently working with Duckcreek P&C tool.
I want to switch my technology  to hadoop.

Can any one tell me the good sites where i can learn from start and find job in hadoop

Answer (score 1):

I suggest these three sites, they are good for start learning such this concepts:

https://www.coursera.org/ : have some courses from big universities all over the word

https://www.edx.org/ : same as coursera

http://bigdatauniversity.com : and IBM website to learn big data and it's applicatoin

there is also another sites for details and learn more concenpts like apache hadoop official website: http://hadoop.apache.org/